# How to generate 2D gaussian with Python?

Tags: python, gaussian

I can generate Gaussian data with `random.gauss(mu, sigma)` function, but how can I generate 2D gaussian? Is there any function like that?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html#scipy.stats.multivariate_normal

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since the standard 2D Gaussian distribution is just the product of two 1D Gaussian distribution, *if there are no correlation between the two axes* (i.e. the covariant matrix is diagonal), just call `random.gauss` twice.

```
def gauss_2d(mu, sigma):
    x = random.gauss(mu, sigma)
    y = random.gauss(mu, sigma)
    return (x, y)
```

Comment: If there are no correlation between the axes, I will call random.gauss twice and I will have 2 1D gaussian dist. Then do I need to product the two 1D gaussian distribution? Or can I just put them as columns of my 2D data? Because if I need to product them together, since I have 10k data, it will cost too much.

Comment: @user984041: No, just treat the results as the coordinates of a 2D point. The product is the reason why this approach is valid.

Comment: Saying to call it twice isn't a sufficient answer. You will have 2 1D arrays. A complete answer would explain how to combine two 1D arrays into a 2D array.

Comment: @Octopus: Sampling a 2D gaussian gives you an array of 2-tuples i.e. 2×N matrix, not a 2D array (N×N matrix). I don't see how it is insufficient.

Comment: I don't know what's meant by calling `random.gauss` twice, please modify your answer

Comment: @shakram02 Literally calling `random.gauss` twice . See update.

Answer (score 72):

If you can use `numpy`, there is [`numpy.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov[, size])`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html).

For example, to get 10,000 2D samples:

```
np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 10000)
```

where `mean.shape==(2,)` and `cov.shape==(2,2)`.

Comment: I am trying to draw 10000 samples from 2D distribution I created like this: data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,(10000,10000)) but it gives memory error. Am I generating a 10000x10000 data or 2x2 data, I am confused a bit. If so, how can I draw 10000 samples from a 2D distribution?

Comment: I believe the correct way to get 10K 2D samples is `np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,10000)`, where `mean.shape==(2,)` and `cov.shape==(2,2)`.

Comment: The above method by @NPE worked for me when I wanted to create multidimensional gaussian data.

Answer (score 27):

I'd like to add an approximation using exponential functions.  This directly generates a 2d matrix which contains a movable, symmetric 2d gaussian.

I should note that I found this code on the scipy mailing list archives and modified it a little.

```
import numpy as np

def makeGaussian(size, fwhm = 3, center=None):
    """ Make a square gaussian kernel.

    size is the length of a side of the square
    fwhm is full-width-half-maximum, which
    can be thought of as an effective radius.
    """

    x = np.arange(0, size, 1, float)
    y = x[:,np.newaxis]

    if center is None:
        x0 = y0 = size // 2
    else:
        x0 = center[0]
        y0 = center[1]

    return np.exp(-4*np.log(2) * ((x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2) / fwhm**2)
```

For reference and enhancements, it is hosted as a gist [here](http://gist.github.com/4635563).  Pull requests welcome!

Comment: Thanks for a way to generate a matrix, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: I might be confused, but is the `center` actually correct? If I do `scipy.ndimage.center_of_mass(makeGaussian(10, 3, center=(4,3)))` I get `(3, 4)`.

Comment: I've also played with it a bit, the centre is indeed falsely placed

Comment: Check if you can simplify this using `np.outer(signal.windows.gaussian(70, 8), signal.windows.gaussian(70, 8))` like in the example on https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html

Answer (score 13):

```py
import numpy as np

# define normalized 2D gaussian
def gaus2d(x=0, y=0, mx=0, my=0, sx=1, sy=1):
    return 1. / (2. * np.pi * sx * sy) * np.exp(-((x - mx)**2. / (2. * sx**2.) + (y - my)**2. / (2. * sy**2.)))

x = np.linspace(-5, 5)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y) # get 2D variables instead of 1D
z = gaus2d(x, y)
```

Straightforward implementation and example of the [2D Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function). Here sx and sy are the spreads in x and y direction, mx and my are the center coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

Numpy has a function to do this. It is documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html). Additionally to the method proposed above it allows to draw samples with arbitrary covariance.

Here is a small example, assuming `ipython -pylab` is started:

```
samples = multivariate_normal([-0.5, -0.5], [[1, 0],[0, 1]], 1000)
plot(samples[:, 0], samples[:, 1], '.')

samples = multivariate_normal([0.5, 0.5], [[0.1, 0.5],[0.5, 0.6]], 1000)
plot(samples[:, 0], samples[:, 1], '.')
```

Comment: Plotting lines should be `plot(samples[:,0], samples[:,1], '.')`

Answer (score 5):

In case someone find this thread and is looking for somethinga little more versatile (like I did), I have modified the code from @giessel. The code below will allow for asymmetry and rotation.

```
import numpy as np

def makeGaussian2(x_center=0, y_center=0, theta=0, sigma_x = 10, sigma_y=10, x_size=640, y_size=480):
    # x_center and y_center will be the center of the gaussian, theta will be the rotation angle
    # sigma_x and sigma_y will be the stdevs in the x and y axis before rotation
    # x_size and y_size give the size of the frame 

    theta = 2*np.pi*theta/360
    x = np.arange(0,x_size, 1, float)
    y = np.arange(0,y_size, 1, float)
    y = y[:,np.newaxis]
    sx = sigma_x
    sy = sigma_y
    x0 = x_center
    y0 = y_center

    # rotation
    a=np.cos(theta)*x -np.sin(theta)*y
    b=np.sin(theta)*x +np.cos(theta)*y
    a0=np.cos(theta)*x0 -np.sin(theta)*y0
    b0=np.sin(theta)*x0 +np.cos(theta)*y0

    return np.exp(-(((a-a0)**2)/(2*(sx**2)) + ((b-b0)**2) /(2*(sy**2))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try just using the `numpy` method `np.random.normal` to generate a 2D gaussian distribution. 
The sample code is `np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (num_samples, 2))`.

A sample run by taking mean = 0 and sigma 20 is shown below :

```
np.random.normal(0, 20, (10,2))

>>array([[ 11.62158316,   3.30702215],
   [-18.49936277, -11.23592946],
   [ -7.54555371,  14.42238838],
   [-14.61531423,  -9.2881661 ],
   [-30.36890026,  -6.2562164 ],
   [-27.77763286, -23.56723819],
   [-18.18876597,  41.83504042],
   [-23.62068377,  21.10615509],
   [ 15.48830184, -15.42140269],
   [ 19.91510876,  26.88563983]])
```

Hence we got 10 samples in a 2d array with mean = 0 and sigma = 20