# How to generate 2 sets of 1000 2D points from Gaussian Distribution having means at [5,5] and [10,10]?

Tags: python-3.x, gaussian

My question is that i want two sets of 1000 2D points each from Gaussian distribution lying on a plane having
same standard deviation of 1.5 and different means at [5,5] and [10,10]. using mean at (5,5) and having standard deviation of 1.

Comment: are you aware of this function https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html ?

Comment: no, i'm not aware of this function.

Comment: Related question with examples for simple uncorrelated 2D gaussian, and numpy multivariate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687679/how-to-generate-2d-gaussian-with-python