# How to create a normal 2d distribution in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, distribution

Given a tensor containing N points, represented in [x,y], I want to create a 2D gaussian distribution around each point, draw them on an empty feature map.

[image]

For example, the left image shows one given point (registered as a pixel on the feature map, whose value is set to 1). The right image adds a 2D guassian distribution around it.

How could I add such distribution for each point? Is there an API for it in pytorch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

##### Sampling from the multivariate normal distribution

You can use [`MultivariateNormal`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html?highlight=multivariate_normal#multinomial) to sample from a multivariate normal.

```
>>> h, w = 200, 200
>>> fmap = torch.zeros(h, w)
```

Fill `fmap` with the origin points:

```
>>> pts = torch.rand(20, 2)
>>> pts *= torch.tensor([h, w])
>>> x, y = pts.T.long()
>>> x, y = x.clip(0, h), y.clip(0, w)

>>> fmap[x, y] = 1
```

Following this, we can sample from the following distribution (*you can adjust the covariance matrix accordingly*):

```
>>> sampler = MultivariateNormal(pts.T, 10*torch.eye(len(pts)))

>>> for x in range(10):
...    x, y = sampler.sample()
...    x, y = x.clip(0, h).long(), y.clip(0, w).long()
...    fmap[x, y] = 1
```

As a result, you can end up with something like:

| Origin points | Normal sampling |
| --- | --- |
| [image: !] | [image: !] |

This is not documented well enough, but you can pass the sample shape to the `sample` function. This allows you to sample multiple points per call, *i.e.* you only need one to populate your canvas.

Here is a function to draw from `MultivariateNormal`:

```
def multivariate_normal_sampler(mean, cov, k):
    sampler = MultivariateNormal(mean, cov)
    return sampler.sample((k,)).swapaxes(0,1).flatten(1)
```

Then you can call it as:

```
>>> x, y = multivariate_normal_sampler(mean=pts.T, cov=50*torch.eye(len(pts)), k=1000)
```

Clip the samples:

```
>>> x, y = x.clip(0, h-1).long(), y.clip(0, w-1).long()
```

Finally insert into fmap and draw:

```
>>> fmap[x, y] += .1
```

Here is an example preview:

| `k=1,000` | `k=50,000` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: !] | [image: !] |

<sub>The utility function is available as  `torch.distributions.multivariate_normal.MultivariateNormal`</sub>

---

##### Computing the density map using the *pdf*

Alternatively, instead of sampling from the normal distribution, you could compute the density values based on its probability density function (*pdf*):

[image: !]

[A particular example of a two-dimensional Gaussian function is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function):

[image]

Origin points:

```
>>> h, w = 50, 50
>>> x0, y0 = torch.rand(2, 20)
>>> origins = torch.stack((x0*h, y0*w)).T
```

Define the [gaussian 2D pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687679/how-to-generate-2d-gaussian-with-python):

```
def gaussian_2d(x=0, y=0, mx=0, my=0, sx=1, sy=1):
    return 1 / (2*math.pi*sx*sy) * \
      torch.exp(-((x - mx)**2 / (2*sx**2) + (y - my)**2 / (2*sy**2)))
```

Construct the grid and accumulate the gaussians from each origin points:

```
x = torch.linspace(0, h, h)
y = torch.linspace(0, w, w)
x, y = torch.meshgrid(x, y)

z = torch.zeros(h, w)
for x0, y0 in origins:
  z += gaussian_2d(x, y, mx=x0, my=y0, sx=h/10, sy=w/10)
```

| Multivariate normal distributions |
| --- |
| [image: !] |

<sub>The code to plot the grid of values is simply using [`matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html): `plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z)`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! My feature map is however not binary, could we assign float value (from 0 to 1) to each pixel near the given points? (instead of adding discrete points around)

Comment: use `fmap[x, y] = 1` to fill all points is very elegant !

Comment: Ps. To avoid *the area between two close points* having larger value than the points themselves, I used `z= torch.max(z, gaussian_2d())` instead of `z += gaussian_2d()`